# C++ Primer chapter 9 does not compile: `useConvs.cc:50:19: error: call of overloaded ‘stod(std::string&)’ is ambiguous`

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11

I bought the C++ Primer 5th edition and downloaded [the accompanying zip file with sources](http://www.informit.com/content/images/9780321714114/downloads/GCC_4_7_0.zip). The zip file is developed for GCC version 4.7.0

I'm on Linux, Ubuntu 13.10 and GCC version 4.8.1

As a sanity check for my system setup and the contents of the download, I tried to compile the examples by typing `make` in the folder where I unpacked the zip file. All examples compiled except for **chapter 9**. I checked the `CompilerNotes.pdf` that came in the zip archive, but it doesn't mention this particular error message.

**My question is**

How can I fix chapter 9 source code in the zip file in such a way that the code compiles as intended *and* the code still reasonably lines up with the book?

**The compiler error is:**

```
g++ -std=c++0x -I.. -I..\7 -c useConvs.cc -o useConvs.o
useConvs.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
useConvs.cc:50:19: error: call of overloaded ‘stod(std::string&)’ is ambiguous
  double d = stod(s);   // converts the string s to floating-point
                   ^
useConvs.cc:50:19: note: candidates are:
In file included from useConvs.cc:33:0:
../Version_test.h:86:8: note: double stod(const string&, std::size_t*)
 double stod(const std::string &s, std::size_t * = 0)
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from ../Version_test.h:70,
                 from useConvs.cc:33:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2853:3: note: double std::stod(const string&, std::size_t*)
```

And the same error is repeated for line 55. Line 50 reads:

```
        double d = stod(s);   // converts the string s to floating-point
```

**The source code:**

```
/*
 * This file contains code from "C++ Primer, Fifth Edition", by Stanley B.
 * Lippman, Josee Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo, and is covered under the
 * copyright and warranty notices given in that book:
 * 
 * "Copyright (c) 2013 by Objectwrite, Inc., Josee Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo."
 * 
 * 
 * "The authors and publisher have taken care in the preparation of this book,
 * but make no expressed or implied warranty of any kind and assume no
 * responsibility for errors or omissions. No liability is assumed for
 * incidental or consequential damages in connection with or arising out of the
 * use of the information or programs contained herein."
 * 
 * Permission is granted for this code to be used for educational purposes in
 * association with the book, given proper citation if and when posted or
 * reproduced.Any commercial use of this code requires the explicit written
 * permission of the publisher, Addison-Wesley Professional, a division of
 * Pearson Education, Inc. Send your request for permission, stating clearly
 * what code you would like to use, and in what specific way, to the following
 * address: 
 * 
 *      Pearson Education, Inc.
 *      Rights and Permissions Department
 *      One Lake Street
 *      Upper Saddle River, NJ  07458
 *      Fax: (201) 236-3290
*/ 

// Version_test.h contains definitions for to_string and stod
// if the compiler does not yet define these functions,
// this code will use the definitions we provide
#include "Version_test.h" 

#include <string>
using std::string;
#ifdef STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS
using std::to_string; using std::stod;
#endif

#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
        int i = 42;
        // converts the int i to its character representation
        string s = to_string(i);  

        double d = stod(s);   // converts the string s to floating-point
        cout << "i = " << i << " s = " << s << " d is: " << d << endl;

        // convert the first substring in s that starts with a digit,  d = 3.14
        string s2 = "pi = 3.14";
        d = stod(s2.substr(s2.find_first_of("+-.0123456789")));

        cout << "d = " << d << " s = " << s << " s2 is: " << s2 << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// Version_test.h contains definitions for to_string and stod
// if the compiler does not yet define these functions,
// this code will use the definitions we provide
#include "Version_test.h"
```

The code in question assumes that the compiler does not have definitions for those functions, and provides it's own definitions in that header. But it seems that in your particular case the compiler *does* provide that functionality and it conflicts with those provided in the zip.

Unqualified lookup finds ::strod, and ADL finds ::std::strod, with the exact same signatures and the compiler cannot determine a better candidate for overload resolution. My guess is that the simple solution is to remove that header, or if your implementation does not provide a `to_string` then comment out the `strod`

Comment: You put me on the right track, I totally missed the mention of `stod` in the comments. Unfortunately my solution is not fit for a comment so I added [an answer of my own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20292700/1264426). It turned out that 4.8.1 supports two features that 4.7.0 didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Try disambiguating the calls by prefixing `std::` wherever `to_string` and `stod` are present:

```
int main()
{
        int i = 42;
        // converts the int i to its character representation
        string s = std::to_string(i);  

        double d = std::stod(s);   // converts the string s to floating-point
        cout << "i = " << i << " s = " << s << " d is: " << d << endl;

        // convert the first substring in s that starts with a digit,  d = 3.14
        string s2 = "pi = 3.14";
        d = std::stod(s2.substr(s2.find_first_of("+-.0123456789")));

        cout << "d = " << d << " s = " << s << " s2 is: " << s2 << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I verified this answer and it works too, but I eventually chose to edit the `Version_test.h` file.

Comment: Similar, but not exactly the same, you could add a local using declaration that will be found by regular lookup before looking at namespace level, blocking lookup from finding `::stod` but both this comment and this answer require the standard library providing the functionality, and if that is the case, the solution is to remove the include altogether

Comment: You can review my edit history to see the insanity of an answer I had before I minimalized it to this. It's a good thing David provided such a succinct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain you line by line what gets wrong in here (I have copied "Version_test.h" inside the main.cpp - that is what `#include` does):

```
#ifndef VERSION_TEST_H
#define VERSION_TEST_H

#if __cplusplus == 201103L 
// base version, future releases of this file will 
// #define these variables as features as they are implemented 

/* Code in this delivery use the following variables to control compilation

   Variable tests           C++ 11 Feature 
HEX_MANIPS               hexfloat and defaultfloat manipulators
REFMEMS                  reference qualified member functions
REGEX                    regular expressions library
STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS     conversions to and from string to numeric
*/
#endif  // ends compiler version check

#ifndef STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS
// if the library doesn't define to_string 
// or the numeric conversion functions
// as a workaround we define to_string and stod in this file

// Readers can ignore the implemnetations of to_string and stod 
// but can use these functions in their code.

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
// we use sprintf from stdio to implement to_string
#include <cstdio>

inline
string to_string(int i)
{
    char buf[100];
    std::sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
    return buf;
}

inline
double stod(const std::string &s, std::size_t * = 0)
{
    char **buf = 0;
    return std::strtod(s.c_str(), buf);
}
#endif   // STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS

#include <iostream>

#ifndef HEX_MANIPS
inline
std::ostream &defaultfloat(std::ostream &os) 
{
    os.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);
    return os;
}
#endif   // HEX_MANIPS

#endif  // ends header guard

#include <string>
using std::string;
#ifdef STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS
using std::to_string; using std::stod;
#endif

#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
        int i = 42;
        // converts the int i to its character representation
        string s = to_string(i);  

        double d = stod(s);   // converts the string s to floating-point
        cout << "i = " << i << " s = " << s << " d is: " << d << endl;

        // convert the first substring in s that starts with a digit,  d = 3.14
        string s2 = "pi = 3.14";
        d = std::stod(s2.substr(s2.find_first_of("+-.0123456789")));

        cout << "d = " << d << " s = " << s << " s2 is: " << s2 << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Let's keep a register of what functions we have declared when `STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS` was not defined.

Take a closer look here:

```
inline
std::string to_string(int i)
{
    char buf[100];
    std::sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
    return buf;
}

inline
double stod(const std::string &s, std::size_t * = 0)
{
    char **buf = 0;
    return std::strtod(s.c_str(), buf);
}
```

You create new functions (don't care about `inline` now - it will work even without these).

We registered:

`string to_string(int i)`

`double stod(const std::string &s, std::size_t * = 0)`

---

Now let's look here.

```
#ifdef STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS
using std::to_string; using std::stod;
#endif
```

We didn't declare `STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS` (that's the case we're looking at, check few lines up) so there is no code here.

Author of the book thought that this will prevent `std::stod` usage (we are not `using std::stod;`), but he or she didn't think about something very important: the line `using std::stod;` is actually written - somewhere in the Standard Library (it can be `<iostream>` or `<cstdlib>`, whatever).
The same situation goes for several different functions like `atoi();` or `atof();`

That's what we actually have declared now:

`string to_string(int i)`

`double stod(const std::string &s, std::size_t * = 0)`

`double std::stod(const std::string &s, std::size_t * = 0)`

`using std::stod` - somewhere in the standard library.

That makes a problem: writing `stod();` will actually refer to two functions (check with the list above).

As long as `stod()` is global (I mean - used without any `std::`) we can do nothing to prevent it from declaration.

In order to keep the book's purposes we should consider what exactly the `STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS` macro is. It asks if there are some *already defined* functions for string conversions. As long as you use any standard library (like `iostream`) you will always have some functions *already defined*.
So the thing is, that when we use any standard library, we declare the macro `STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS`, and when we don't use any standard library (and we always do) we don't declare the macro.
We use such libraries (and hence, even between the `#ifndef` and `#endif` we include such libs) so we declare the macro. Corrected, working code:

```
#define STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS

#include "Version_test.h"

#include <string>
using std::string;
#ifdef STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS
using std::to_string; using std::stod;
#endif

#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
        int i = 42;
        // converts the int i to its character representation
        string s = to_string(i);  

        double d = stod(s);   // converts the string s to floating-point
        cout << "i = " << i << " s = " << s << " d is: " << d << endl;

        // convert the first substring in s that starts with a digit,  d = 3.14
        string s2 = "pi = 3.14";
        d = std::stod(s2.substr(s2.find_first_of("+-.0123456789")));

        cout << "d = " << d << " s = " << s << " s2 is: " << s2 << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: *she didn't think [...] the line using std::stod; is actually written - somewhere in the Standard Library* No, that line is not written anywhere and it need not be to break the code. The problem is that it lives inside `std` and ADL will find it even without the using declaration as the argument is really a `std::string` that also lives in the `std` namespace.

Comment: Ok, it makes a lot of sense, but we've got such compiler error: `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2853:3: note: double std::stod(const string&, std::size_t*)`.
This (`double std::stod`)means that `stod` is declared **inside** std. The same applied for Visual Studio.
Anyway, the result is the same - ambiguous call - and we can do nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

[David Rodríguez - dribeas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20292384/1264426) put me on the right track, but the comments are not fit for a code sniplet that covers couple lines.

I solved the compiler errors by adding the following two lines in `../Version_test.h`:

```
#define REFMEMS
#define STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS
```

I added them after this paragraph on lines 48-60:

```
#if __cplusplus == 201103L 
// base version, future releases of this file will 
// #define these variables as features as they are implemented 

/* Code in this delivery use the following variables to control compilation

   Variable tests           C++ 11 Feature 
HEX_MANIPS               hexfloat and defaultfloat manipulators
REFMEMS                  reference qualified member functions
REGEX                    regular expressions library
STRING_NUMERIC_CONVS     conversions to and from string to numeric
*/
#endif  // ends compiler version check
```

Comment: You know you could have added them to the makefile or as an environment variable and leave the code untouched so that it would work in older compilers like the one it was intended for. [I did not take the time to figure out what defines needed to be passed in to avoid those declarations]

Comment: you need to edit makefile and add -DSTRING_NUMERIC_CONVS to C++ compiler flags.